# Error using JNI with the machine created header file

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface, syntax-error

My JNI was working fine as far as i remember a couple of days. Now i am getting the error:

```
DODJNI.h:15: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘void’
```

However this is the machine created header file and so presumly there should be no errors with the header file, as it says at the top to not modify it

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class DoDJNI */

#ifndef _Included_DoDJNI
#define _Included_DoDJNI
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     DoDJNI
 * Method:    parseCommand
 * Signature: (Ljava/lang/String;)V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_DoDJNI_parseCommand
  (JNIEnv *, jobject, jstring);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

Comment: The file looks okay. So the environment must have changed, e.g. the file jni.h being no longer accessible. Was this the only error message you got? Did you use different compiler options?

Comment: this could also happen if the C file that include DODJNI.h has some bad symbol before the `#include ` statement